# When it comes to Android resources, what is a bag?

Tags: java, android, c++, bag

I'm digging down into some of the low level native Android code. I'm trying to learn how the framework ultimately fills in an attribute set. I'm digging around [here](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp#1329)
and I keep running into "bag". I don't have a good mental picture of what this is..

1. We have [`bag_entry`s](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#1584)
2. We can [lock/unlock](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp#3751) it
3. Our style attribute finder is of type [`BagAttributeFinder`](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_AssetManager.cpp#1321)

Is this an acronym for something? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here that should make my mental abstraction just click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is a type of Data Structure called the bag.

"A bag is a collection where removing items is not supported—its purpose is to provide clients with the ability to collect items and then to iterate through the collected items. Stats.java is a bag client that reads a sequence of real numbers from standard input and prints out their mean and standard deviation."

Source: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/

Comment: thx. I'm familiar with "bag of words" from computer vision. I guess this works the same way.